# WinSCP creates new session on every WebDAV call

Tags: webdav, winscp

I tried out different WebDAV clients and all of them behave a little different. In this special case I use WinSCP to connect to a SabreDAV based, self written (in php), WebDAV server which emulates a filesystem.

The problem I have is that WinSCP creates - unlike several other WebDAV clients (eg BitKinex, CarotDAV) - a new php session each time I do a command (refresh, upload file, ...).

So is there a possibility to ensure reusing session (programmatically on server side) or do I need to set a specific option in WinSCP? If the latter one, I could not figure out so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I implemented a workaround that allows me to mostly reuse same session every time.

Hopefully WinSCP will process cookies one time though to be sure.

Comment: The correct solution is to _not_ rely on session cookies. It's bad design and you should really avoid them if you can (which is most HTTP APIs, but just not browser clients).

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP indeed does not process HTTP cookies.

I've never seen a WebDAV server that would require it. The cookies are definitely not mentioned in WebDAV specifications. WebDAV servers that need to authentication or track its users use HTTP authentication. Not cookies.

Anyway, I've added a request for processing cookies to WinSCP tracker:
https://winscp.net/tracker/1419

Comment: But I *do* HTTP authentication and the clients send the _Authorization_ header on every request, but I would like to track their _session_ as well which is stored in cookie `PHPSESSID` as default in php. All other clients I have tested so far do accept the _Set-Cookie_ response header from server and send it back to server on every further request so he can track and use same session. Are you with me now?